# why can't I Import UIKit in my swift file?

Tags: swift, xcode

I can Import UIKit in other files in my project but not in this one why?[image]

Comment: Just type it in. What happens?

Comment: Hi Lucas, 
how did you solve this bug?

Answer (score 3):

If Firebase or FirebaseAuth use

```
@_exported import UIKit
```

it will import UIKit for you, and therefore you won't be able to import UIKit because it will already be imported.  For more information consider what [this website](https://theswiftdev.com/2018/03/29/everything-about-public-and-private-swift-attributes/) says about @_exported:

"If you want to import an external module for your whole module you can use the 
   @_exported keyword before your import. From now the imported module will be 
   available everywhere"

It also says you should probably not use @_exported because it is a private swift attribute.

If this is the case, then UIKit should already be imported, and you should be able to use it without explicitly importing it.

Comment: I would add that nothing happens if you import UIKit anyway, I would actually encourage adding it regardless in case you remove the offending library.